# Android: percentage width without changing height

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to create text field which takes 70% of layout's width (in linear layout). I use this code:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/phone"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight=".7"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="phone" >
```

The problem is that in such case height also takes 70% of layout's height - but I don't need to change it, just want it to be "wrap_content". Is there any good solution?

**UPD:**
Would it be a good solution if I create a new horizontal-orientated linear layout and place my text field inside it? Or maybe something more elegant?

**UPD(2):**
I want it to look like below, but without using marginLeft and marginRgiht, which would give different percentage on a different screen resolution

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set `weightSum` on the parent of the control if you intend to use the weight. So yeah, put it in a LinearLayout and give the layout the proper parameters. Also, please remember that weight only affects the EXTRA space, so you want to set the width to 0dp, so the entire available space is considered "extra" space. Lastly, I think using integers for weight might be faster, but I'm not sure about that.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="4">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/phone"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="phone" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**UPDATE:**
If you want it centered as well, then include some spacer views to the left and to the right, with the proper weights:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".15" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/phone"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".7"
        android:inputType="phone" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".15" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: no there is no need to set weightSum, which is 1 by default. You can always give float numbers like ".5", ".9", etc...

Comment: This doesn't give answer to my question - it still doesn't work.

Comment: I've tried it and it works quite nicely. Are you SURE you set the width to 0dp and included it in a LinearLayout with width fill_parent? Just copy-paste my code in a layout and it should work...

Comment: @GökhanBarışAker actually, if you don't set the weightSum, it doesn't work for whatever reason (tested on Android 2.3.3).

Comment: I just noticed you updated your question with the request that you want the field to be centered as well, so I included an update showing how to use transparent spacer views to achieve that goal.

Comment: @AlexandruCristescu yes, that's my mistake - it works. But still, I have vertical linear layout as a parent. If I want to create another text field with the same properties, I need to create another linear layout for it (see picture in UPD№2). Doesn't that sound a little bit hacky? What if I have 15 text field, do I need to create 15 layouts for them? Maybe some more simple way to do that?

Comment: @YuriyPogrebnyak well it's a weird solution for a weird request :) The usual way to have fields with spacing on the left and right is not to say "I want 70%" of the width, but instead use left and right margins specified in dp. As you say, this will lead to the field not always being 70% of the width of the parent, but always CLOSE to it. If for whatever reason you want it to be exactly 70%, the yes, jump through the hoops...

Comment: @AlexandruCristescu well, I'll try to use margins instead of percentage, if the difference between visualisation on low- and high-resolution screen isn't very big. Anyway, thanks for good explanation

Answer (score 2):

[image]
Hi As per your code if you are going to set weight means normally we should not set layout width to wrap content or fill parent.  it should be zero.  so it should be like this.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/phone"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_weight=".7"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="phone" >
```

else if you will try with the following code means you will get it like the image

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_margin="30dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/phone"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="phone" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/phone"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="phone" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Like above image

Comment: Thanks, but, again, if to use dp's, it would give DIFFERENT percentage on different screen resolution. Can I do smth like that using percentage but not actual size in pixels?

Comment: percentage wont get support in xml design file. we cant set as a width or height using %

Answer (score 0):

give **Margin Layout_left/Right** padding for Editext.

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/phone"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_weight=".7"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
android:inputType="phone" >
```

Answer (score 0):

While it's possible to solve with LinearLayout weights it's also possible to achieve with [ConstraintLayout guidelines](https://medium.com/google-developers/building-interfaces-with-constraintlayout-3958fa38a9f7#4511). Just add two vertical guidelines with 15% and 85% position values and constrain EditText width to those guidelines:

[image: Layout Editor]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.EditText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="1st EditText"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/startGuideline"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/endGuideline" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="2nd EditText"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/startGuideline"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/endGuideline" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/startGuideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.15" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/endGuideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.85" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```